# Добавление JSON данных в базу MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

Необходимо распарсить полученный JSON и добавить эти данные в таблицу. Добавление будет происходить при двух условиях.

1. При наличии записи с тем же ID необходимо обновить поля.
2. Если нет такого ID то просто добавить запись.

Я застрял с переборкой, получил двумерный массив, а теперь незнаю как правильно провести переборку:

```
    <?php
//Прием JSON-а
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if (!is_array($data)) die('Json convert error');
//соединяемся с БД 
function dbConnect(){
//$cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tosekdb");
$cn = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");
return $cn;
}
//var_dump($cn);
return $cn;
}       
// Данные с базы для сравнения
$dbselect = mysqli ($cn, "SELECT pos_id FROM db");
mysqli_close($cn);
// Парсинг JSON-а
foreach($data as $element) {
    $fields = array();
    $values = array();
    foreach ($element as $field_name => $field_value) {
    $fields[] = $field_name;
    $values[] = $field_value;
}
}
for($i=0;$i<count($element);$i++){
    if ($values['id'] = $dbselect['id']) {
        $sql = ($cn, "UPDATE db SET 
name=".$values["name"]."count=".$values["count"]."artikul=".$values["atr"]" 
WHERE pos_id=".$values["id"])
    }
    else
        $sql = ($cn, "INSERT INTO db(name,count,atr,pos_id) VALUES 
("$values["name"].", ".$values["count"].",".$values["atr"].", 
".$values["id"])
  }


?>
```

Comment: *1. При наличии записи с тем же ID необходимо обновить поля. 2. Если нет такого ID то просто добавить запись.* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: *получил двумерный массив, а теперь не знаю как правильно провести переборку* Если версия MySQL позволяет (5.7.8 или старше) - разумнее не заниматься самодеятельностью, а передавать на сервер непосредственно JSON. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: Мне не нужна команда INSERT и UPDATE, интересует переборка и постановка цикла, я имею многомерный массив и теперь его нужно перебрать и сравнить, вот в этом в голове неукладка

Comment: С частью обработке на базе вообще незнаком, да и мне нужно сравнить значения базы и JSON-а, разве по базе так получиться?

Comment: *так получится?* Да. *С частью обработки на базе вообще не знаком* Знакомьтесь - тем более что и повод есть. Делать вручную на клиенте (и наверняка делать плохо) то, что сервер умеет делать хорошо - это глупость.

Comment: Если у вас там 2 поля, то у вас только цикл обхода пришедших записей внутри которого единственный insert (с опцией on duplicate key update, конечно), причем подготовленный заранее и внутри цикла только привязка параметров и execute. ничего заранее селектить из БД и сравнивать на клиенте не надо

Comment: Пять полей будет прилетать, по одному полю сравнение.